# How does websockets deal with for two tabs of the same browser

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, cookies, websocket

I have

- 1 PHP server (serving http request) and
- 1 node.js publishing updated data messages (with websockets to each connection).

The php server setup its cookie.  In one browser, this cookie is available across all tabs.

When a browser has 2 tabs opened to the domain, there is only one cookie identifying the browser, but 1 message of updated data must be sent to each tabs.

1. **What is the traditional way to distinguish between tabs ?**
2. **Should I use another cookie (managed by node.js) to distinguish between each browser tabs ?**

Comment: You should have a different websocket for each tab.  Each page in each tab would create it's own websocket connection to the server (websockets aren't shared among tabs).  It would be up to the server to then send any data for that user to each websocket that was associated with the target user.

Comment: if you broadcast, you don't need individual identification. if you need individual id, then you'll need more cookies/otkens

Comment: @jfriend00 but how to distinguish between each tabs instance, since cookies are shared across tab, I guess each javascript environment (each tab) must identify itself on connection ? Both then, how to distinguish a request received from one tab to avoid sending to this tab again the update data they just requested ?

Comment: @dandavis what is an otkens ? If you meant tokens, how should deal with this discrete element, establish on each websocket connexion and then provided on each php request ?

Comment: There's a separate websocket for each tab.  That's how you distinguish.  If you're keeping separate state per tab in your server and you want to allow multiple connections by the same user, then you have to keep the state per websocket connection, not per user.  You don't need to create a separate cookie per tab because the websocket itself already serves as the unique id for each tab.

Comment: @jfriend00, based on all these comments, I guess that each php request must contain the tabs websocket id, to let php know from which tab the request was perform from, and then allow node.js to broadcast all updated data to other tabs (excluding the initial requester websocket), therefore, keeping a sort of session state of each tabs websocket.  Is that correct ?

Comment: I turned my comments so far into an answer and attempted to answer the latest comment question you posted in that answer.

Comment: @jfriend00, so far your comments seems to be the appropriate answer, can you publish your comments in 1 answer, outside of the comments area ?

Comment: Already did make an answer.

Comment: For future reference, [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/386485/40065) is a similar question on SoftwareEngineering that I asked a few minutes ago: 
How does websockets deal with for two tabs of the same browser ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer...

There's a separate websocket for each tab. That's how you distinguish different tabs from each other. If you're keeping separate state per tab in your server and you want to allow multiple connections by the same user, then you have to keep the state per websocket connection (you can use the websocket id), not per user.

You don't need to create a separate cookie per tab because the websocket itself already serves as the unique id for each tab.

You haven't said if your app wants identical state in all tabs or if each tab has different state and you would handle things a bit differently on the server side based on the desire.  If you want all tabs to receive the same data, then whenever you want to send data to a client, you have to find all websockets that are associated with a given user and send the same data to them.

If you want each tab to behave independently, then you just keep server-side state per websocket and send a response only to the websocket that the response belongs to, not all websockets associated with that user.

As with nearly all questions here on SO, it's a lot easier to answer more specifically if you tell us more about what you're actually doing rather than having a theoretical conversation.  For example, if we knew how your app was supposed to work with different tabs, then we'd know which behavior path to follow.