# redundant HTML notifications by several tabs

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

my pages using socket.io for real-time notification. it works well. however, opening several tabs (i.e. https://mypage.com/, https://mypage.com/settings, https://mypage.com/list) cause multiple notifications.

i knew facebook web using notification for new post or new messages, and that notification are unique. (in spite of several tabs!) i wonder how it possible.

i tried sockets classify by ip and send one notification to one of them. but it is not gorgeous.

is there any other methods or strategy for unique notification?

Comment: TL;DR: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23300615/438992. Nutshell: don't do notifications based on all user's websockets.

Comment: Is every new tab a new client socket?

Comment: @GrafiCode yes. all tabs create each sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in server-side, i add 'noti count' that identify each notifications and serve this value with original data.

in client-side, using localStorage to share 'noti count' value among tabs, verify this notification event is already shown.

localStorage.getItem and localStorage.setItem is slow and socket events arrives at the same time, so 'noti count' value from localStorage is not updated by other tabs.

i added setTimeout for wait 0~10000 ms for each events. finally, socket shows unique notification!

but it has hazard when random timeout is similar to each other, getItem get value before setItem which updates 'noti count'. in this case, redundant notification shown. (at first, i set random timeout to 0~1000, lots of redundant notification shown) increase max of random timeout increases stability to unfortunately similar timeout. but it also increases hazard of order ensuring.

to ensure notification order, add notification queue and adjust random timeout to pop notification.